# Tabulate a data frame in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I wanted to tabulate data so that a factor variable becomes columns and  keep  value from another variable in cell.

So I tried,

```
a=rep(1:3,3)
d<-rep(1:3, each=3)
b=rnorm(9)
c=runif(9)
dt<-data.frame(a,d,b,c)

  a d          b         c
1 1 1  0.3819762 0.5199602
2 2 1  0.3896063 0.9144730
3 3 1  2.4356972 0.2888464
4 1 2  1.2697016 0.9831191
5 2 2 -1.9844689 0.2046947
6 3 2  0.3473766 0.4766178
7 1 3 -1.5461235 0.6187189
8 2 3  1.0829027 0.9089551
9 3 3 -0.1305324 0.6326141
```

I looked for `data.table`, `plyr`, `reshape2` but could not find what I wanted to do. So, I did the old loop way.

```
mat<-matrix(NA, nrow=3, ncol=4)


for (i in 1:3){
  mat[i,1]<-i
  for (j in 1:3){
    val=dt[a==i & d==j,3]
    mat[i,j+1]<-val

  }

}



mat
     [,1]      [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
[1,]    1 0.3819762  1.2697016 -1.5461235
[2,]    2 0.3896063 -1.9844689  1.0829027
[3,]    3 2.4356972  0.3473766 -0.1305324
```

... and it takes forever for big data.

Any better option??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in base R also:

```
reshape(dt,timevar="d",idvar="a",drop="c",direction="wide")
```

For your data, this gives...

```
  a       b.1        b.2        b.3
1 1 0.3819762  1.2697016 -1.5461235
2 2 0.3896063 -1.9844689  1.0829027
3 3 2.4356972  0.3473766 -0.1305324
```

Please use `set.seed` before drawing simulated data, so that it is easier to reproduce.

I don't know that this solution will be fast. Also, to use it in the future, you have to get used to these confusing argument names ("timevar", "idvar", etc.) which probably don't describe what you're actually doing most of the time...

Comment: Thanks, yeah.I see even using these packages I could not figure out those argument names.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `data.table` option:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(dt)

dt[, as.list(b), by = a]
```

Answer (score 1):

using reshape2

```
> library(reshape2)
> dcast(dt, a ~ d, value.var = "b")
  a         1          2          3
1 1 0.3819762  1.2697016 -1.5461235
2 2 0.3896063 -1.9844689  1.0829027
3 3 2.4356972  0.3473766 -0.1305324
```